# initializing and incrementing a variable in one line of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, erb

Is this the DRYest way to do it in ruby?

```
<% for item in @items %>
  <%= n = n + 1 rescue n = 1 %>
<% end %>
```

which initializes "n" to '1" and increments it as the loop progresses (and prints it out) since this is in one my app's views

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
<% for item in @items %>
  <%= n = n ? n+1 : 1 %>
<% end %>
```

But, depending on what you're trying to do, I'm guessing an each_with_index would be more appropriate

```
<% @items.each_with_index do |item, n| %>
  <%= n %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah nice, I guess the second option is what I was looking for.

Comment: Also is there a way to assign an initial value to "n"?

Comment: Assign an initial value and then increment by 1 each time? The index isn't a counter - it's an index. If you want to increase it by a fixed offset, just add it when you print: <%= n + 5 %>

Answer (score 6):

You could also rely on ruby's nil coercion to an integer which results in zero.

```
<% for item in @items %>
  <%= n = n.to_i + 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Um.

```
n = @items.size
```

Comment: No, @items.size is a constant (within a loop scope)

Comment: Ah, I assume you mean that you're doing something [i]else[/i] with it in the loop, not shown in your example?